# Exponentiation property of the modulo operator

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules, exponentiation, universal-property

On [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-exponentiation) I have found this property:

$$ A^B \; \text{mod} \; C = ( (A \; \text{mod} \; C)^B ) \; \text{mod} \; C $$

with (of course) $A,B,C \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I was wondering how you can prove it.

I thought to write:
$ A = C \cdot m + r $ with $ 0 \le r < C $

So that:
$ A \; \text{mod} \; C = r $

And

$ A^B = (C \cdot m + r)^B = \sum\limits_{k=0}^B \binom{B}{k} (C \cdot m)^k r^{B-k}$

But now?

Comment: Show that $(AB)\text{ mod } C = ((A\text{ mod }C)(B\text{ mod }C))\text{ mod } C$, then it will follow from viewing $A^B$ as $A$ multiplied by itself $B$ times. The negative $B$ case, though, isn't (obviously) well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in your binomial formula all terms in $(Cm)^k\equiv 0\pmod C$ except for $k=0$, so you are left with $r^B$.

Since $r=A \pmod C$ you have proved the statement.